# Green function in non-relativistic quantum mechanics for particles with complicated isotropic spectrum

Tags: quantum-mechanics, greens-functions

Let's consider a free particle with some non-trivial isotropic spectrum. What I mean is that Hamiltonian of the particle depends only on the square of the momentum:
$$\hat{H}=f(\mathbf{\hat{p}}^2)$$
and we consider a plane wave solution of Schrodinger equation:
$$\hat{H}\psi = E\psi$$
$$\psi = e^{i\mathbf{pr}}$$
This gives us an equation for spectrum:
$$E(\mathbf{p})=f(\mathbf{p}^2)$$

Now, I want to find a Green function $G_E(\mathbf{r})$ for our case (supposing $E>0$).

For example, if we have a classical spectrum:
$$\hat{H}=\frac{\mathbf{\hat{p}}^2}{2m}$$
Then the Green function is:
$$G_E(\mathbf{r})=-\frac{e^{ipr/\hbar}}{4\pi r}$$
$\textbf{Question:}$
I wonder if this expression can be expanded to the general case I described previously.So,  is it true that for spectrum $E=f(\mathbf{p}^2)$ one can write the Green in the same way $G_E(\mathbf{r})=-\frac{e^{ipr/\hbar}}{4\pi r}$, assuming that $p=\sqrt{f^{-1}(E)}$? As far as I know, for relativstic spectrum $E^2=p^2c^2+m^2c^4$, one can actually do this.

Answer (score 1):

It depends a bit on the definition of the Green's function. If you define it
as the kernel of the resolvent of the Hamiltonian in the coordinate
representation, then, with ${Im}z\neq 0$,
\begin{eqnarray*}
G(\mathbf{x,y},z) &=&<\mathbf{x}|[z-H]^{-1}|\mathbf{y}>=\int d\mathbf{k}<%
\mathbf{x}|\mathbf{k}>\frac{1}{z-f(k^{2})}<\mathbf{k}|\mathbf{y}> \\
&=&(2\pi )^{-3}\int d\mathbf{k}\exp [i\mathbf{k\cdot (x-y})]\frac{1}{%
z-f(k^{2})} \\
&=&\frac{1}{2\pi ^{2}|\mathbf{x-y}|}\int_{0}^{\infty }dkk\frac{\sin k|%
\mathbf{x-y}|}{z-f(k^{2})}.
\end{eqnarray*}
The further evaluation depends on the form of $f$. Since the integrand is
even in $k$ you can change the $k$-integral in one over $\mathbb{R}$. Next
you can write the sin-function as the difference of two exponentials which
can be continued analytically in opposite half planes. In case $%
f(k^{2})=k^{2}$ you can pick up the pole contributions. For more general $f$
it depends on the situation.